# pynotify linux changing the text

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint, pynotify

I'm using the pynotify module in python in linux (linux mint 15), and I want to know if there's a good way to change the text in a notification without making a new notification.

So lets say I have this:

```
pynotify.init("app_name")
n = pynotify.Notification("", "message A", icon='some_icon')
n.set_urgency(pynotify.URGENCY_CRITICAL)
n.set_timeout(1000)
n.show()
```

If I wanted to make it so the notification said "message B" instead, is that possible without making a new notification? I'm looking to change the notification on the fly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Notification.update`

```
pynotify.init("app_name")
n = pynotify.Notification("", "message A", icon='some_icon')
n.set_urgency(pynotify.URGENCY_CRITICAL)
n.set_timeout(1000)
n.show()
n.update("","message B")
n.show()
```